# Deleting a pointer to this from class?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a class called `SpriteX` which basically is a generic sprite. I also have a class called `_Drawables` which has a member `std::vector<SpriteX*>`. In `main()` every sprite I create can be inserted into the `_Drawables` container and then can call the `drawAll()` method to draw all the `SpriteX` objects in the `std::vector`.

Each `SpriteX` object has knows which index the pointer to itself is located, and in its destructor, it sets the pointer to `NULL`. But I want to completely destroy the pointer, not just set it to `NULL`. But is deleting the pointer safe? If I use `delete` in the destructor, and that calls the destructor, would that cause a loop? Is there any way to release the memory.

Comment: Side note: The name `_Drawables` is illegal in C++; you should rename that class. Names starting with underscore + capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use delete in the destructor and that calls the destructor, would that cause a loop?

Yes, that will probably result in a stack overflow and a crash.

But you don't need to do that, since if you're in the destructor, you're already deleting the memory, right? (as in, you're not explicitly calling the destructor I hope)

Comment: The destructor doesn’t “delete memory” in itself. It merely executes the object’s destruction logic. The memory is released by `delete` *after* calling the object’s destructor.

Comment: No, you're not. You can call `MyClass::~MyClass` manually, and it even makes sense in some situation (placement new, for instance).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The destructor is called when the sprite goes out of scope (i.e. end of `main()`). But what you're saying is, the destructor deletes memory the pointer holds?

Comment: @rcplusplus if sprite goes out of scope, it means you create it in automatic memory (i.e. you're not allocating memory with `new`). Which means the memory is freed automatically, you don't need (nor shouldn't you) to clear it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Boost::shared_ptr<>`

so declare your vector to be:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<SpriteX> >
```

Then when you erase the iterator or clear the entry the reference count will go to zero and the memory will be released.

If you are already in your destructor it wouldn't make sense to delete `this` as you are in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel here, and you aren’t doing it well (it’s a complicated wheel).

Use a smart pointer here, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` (if you’re on C++11) or `boost::shared_ptr`.

> If I use delete in the destructor, and that calls the destructor, would that cause a loop?

Yes. And it makes no sense … how is the destructor called in the first place? Are you actually manually invoking the destructor on a pointer? While that’s possible, it’s most likely a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to forgo pointers entirely and just use a `std::vector<SpriteX>`.

Or, if you want to have pointers but won't be clearing them until the end of `main()`, consider a `boost::ptr_vector`. It will give you the same syntax as a `std::vector<>`, with the exception that you'll have to `push_back` using pointers. In addition it will take ownership of your pointers, so you won't have to worry about deleting them.

Use a `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<SpriteX> >` if you're passing the `SpriteX` individually into functions, or if they have a complicated lifecycle. If they are defined and deleted in the same scope, though, I'd stick to something simpler.

Comment: Problem is, I call move-type methods on the actual object, the `_Drawables` class just prevents me from calling `draw()` explicitly on every `SpriteX` object